# Is there a Swiftier way to access a multi-tiered JSON object in lldb?

Tags: json, swift, lldb

I finally managed to access a tiered structure based on a JSON API return. Now that I was at least successful, I was wondering if anyone can suggest a better way with `lldb` to access values. I am old-school. I need to be able to break a run and pick apart my variables.

I have included three tiers of po calls in LLDB to show my logical progression.

[image: logical steps to get to the layered data]

Comment: Interesting use case. I would recommend Codable in 99.9999% of cases, but here, an old-fashioned JSON library would make the most sense!

Comment: I typically use https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift to setup my JSON-based classes for ease of coding, but darn-it, this kind of thing should be just so much easier and logical. I rely on LLDB so much, i just couldn't let this one go. Even the above took way too many tried to succeed.

Comment: Codable only makes sense from a compiled context. Given that you can't hotswap the definitions of types and `init(from: Decoder)` and `encode(to: Encoder)`, it won't be useful from a JIT context. I would use a third party library, like in the pre-Codable days